# Flask+Apache and 500 Error

Tags: python, apache, flask

I am using Flask and Apache to build a website and the site is up and running.

However I met this strange 500 error: one 500 error will take the website down, and the site will never come online again until I restart apache. I expect Flask+Apache can serve the next visitor after the 500 error, anyway, Flask is thread local.

Assuming the following occassion:

```
@app.route('/<ExpectSomeInteger>')
def hello_world(ExpectSomeInteger):
    aNumber = int(ExpectSomeInteger)
    .....
```

Obviously the code above is faulty and it should use `<int:ExpectSomeInteger>` and stuff. 
If some visitor typed some letters in the "ExpectSomeInteger"'s place, then flask will return a 500 error.

The disaster is apache will send a 500 error page to all visitors after that! I can only restart apache to make it work again!

Is it normal?

I remember when I visit some PHP+MySQL site, even after some very serious errors, the site can serve the next visitor as normal.

Comment: What are you using to host the app? mod_wsgi?

Comment: I installed the following `apt-get install libapache2-mod-python` and 
`sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi`

Comment: @GabySolis: Did you follow the [`mod_wsgi` deployment guide](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/mod_wsgi/)?

Comment: I'd bet you are using mod_python. You shouldn't be using it because the project is dead and has many issues, one of which is that the Python code is only loaded when Apache starts, meaning if your program crashes, it won't restart itself.

Comment: I am pretty sure I did. I looked up lots of documents before I wrote the code. I only changed `WSGIDaemonProcess yourapplication user=user1 group=group1 threads=5` into ``WSGIDaemonProcess myapplicationname user=www-data group=www-data threads=14` I read the document https://beagle.whoi.edu/redmine/projects/ibt/wiki/Deploying_Flask_Apps_with_Apache_and_Mod_WSGI

Comment: @GabySolis: Does your application actually function properly?

Comment: I already removed mod_python `apt-get remove libapache2-mod-python`. Everything seems fine now! Thanks @Sasha Chedygov!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Sasha Chedygov and my site is working fine now.

The problem is I installed something called "mod-python" by following Linode's Library:
https://library.linode.com/web-servers/apache/installation/ubuntu-10.04-lucid

After I did "apt-get remove libapache2-mod-python", Everything seems fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a type converter into the route:

```
@app.route('/<int:an_integer>')
def hello_world(an_integer):
    ...
```

Now, `an_integer` is guaranteed to be an integer. When you pass anything other than an integer, a 404 response is sent.

Comment: @GabySolis: Well, the way you had it wasn't correct. What does your Apache config file look like?